Determine if a stored procedure parameter is optional from C#
I am calling a T-SQL stored procedure from C#, and I want to determine if one of the parameters is optional, so that I know that I can safely ignore it.
None of the provided properties seems to help.
using (var c = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[sp_MyProc]", c))
{
    SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);

    for (int i = 0; i < cmd.Parameters.Count; i++)
    {
        var param = cmd.Parameters[i];
        /* 
             Is there some way at this point to see if a param is an optional parameter? 
        */
    }
}


Only by retrieving the proc definition and parsing it out of that AFAIK https://stackoverflow.com/q/14652361/73226

Does this answer your question? SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command) and IsNullable

Thanks to both MartinSmith and ThomA, those links provided me the information I needed.  Basically, I will need to query SQL Server directly and parse the procedure definition.

You can use TSqlParser which is very easy from C#. I wouldn't waste time on pure sql solutions. Although, doing something like: set fmtonly on exec <yourproc> default, ..., defaultN and replace the default with nulls can help sniff out the defaults as well

I don't quite agree that this is a duplicate question, but the comments and links will get others to the correct answer so good enough for me.  Thanks all for the info.

Hmm, I suppose the C# angle does mean that the answers could use different approaches than the dupes (e.g. TSqlParser  )

My initial thoughts were that this seems backwards and instead, you should be coding specifically to call the SP, no? A class (or method I suppose) should be generating the appropriate parameters and understand the logic behind what is required and when? Pardon my ignorance here and feel free to tell me not to hijack the comments!

@ClearlyClueless, A rational assumption.  In my scenario, I can't depend on how the  SP is coded and want to be able to handle any mismatch intelligently or return a useful error.

What a shame that sys.parameters has_default_value is only applicable to CLR based programmability
